# How to remove children from a UIView in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've this...

```
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIView[] seqPages;
    ...
}

private void loadApp()
{
     int seqCount=5;
     for (int i = 0; i < seqCount; i++)
        {
            seqPages[i] = new UIView()
            {
                Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, vpWidth, vpHeight)
            };
            string s = app.sequence[i];
            var img = UIImage.FromFile("pages/myimg.png");
            UIImageView imgView = new UIImageView(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000));
            imgView.Image = img;
            imgView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
            seqPages[i].Add(imgView);
            mainContainer.Add(seqPages[i]);
        }
}
private void removePage(index){
   //Remove the children of seqPages UIVIew array
}
```

So,on the comment "//Remove the children of seqPages UIVIew array" I need something like : seqPages[index].removeAllChildren();

I was unable to find on Google how to archive this. Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIView` has a `RemoveFromSuperview` method that will remove it from its "parent":

```
foreach (var view in this.View.Subviews)
{
    view.RemoveFromSuperview();
}
```